# Nook Simple Touch, Zoom On Picture

Tags: nook, image, nook-simple-touch

I have a Nook Simple Touch.  One of my `.epub` files contains an image.  The image is pretty small.  How do I zoom in on it?

(With a Nook Color, I double-tap to zoom, but this doesn't seem to work on the Simple Touch.)